# My App keeps on crashing without calling "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" method

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, appdelegate

My App keeps on crashing even it is not calling the AppDelegate Method.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

What is happening that.
 It runs First time smoothly now When I run second time it crashes. This is happening even times (One by one) I run the App. Means First time run, it runs, then second time crashes, third time runs, fourth time crashes, etc....

MAC OSX version: 10.8.4

XCode Version: 4.6.2

Suggest me What should I do?

Comment: So you run it once, then exit with the home button and when you tap the app icon again it crashes?

Comment: Simulator or device? What is the exception?

Comment: update Xcode to 4.6.3

Comment: Wait wait, can you share the piece of code that you have written in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? Well, I have a strong feeling it is because of the code, if the app can be launched for 1st, 3rd, .. n+1 th time then it should launch for all N times, else it shouldn't launch for all N times.

Comment: @PinkFloydRocks It isn't crashing for foreground & background. It is crashing when run through xcode.

Comment: @Wain It is simulator. No any Exceptions. Below is my backtrace result.
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x93650a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
 frame #0: 0x93650a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10

 #1 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101

 #2 libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140

 #3 GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348

 #4 GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123

 #5 GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36

 #6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
 
 #7 AppName`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3bc) + 141 at main.m:40
 
 #8 AppName`start + 53

Comment: @RenoJones I have just create nested Directory structure, initialize local database, SideBar navigation Initialization and Navigation Controller Initialization. Nothing else more than this. And App didn't call the AppDelegate method. It is surprising why it is not calling.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I will update soon and then try to run. Let see what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bug with the version of Xcode you're running when used with the version of Mac OS X you're using. This is specific to running in the simulator, not on a device. Updating Xcode will resolve the issue.

Comment: May be possible. Yes I don't have device so I cant device test.